# How to refresh react page after error handling

Tags: reactjs

I have the following:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
      <NavBar />
</ErrorBoundary>


<ErrorBoundary>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={mainPage} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={buyerPage} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={sellerPage} />
        </Switch>
</ErrorBoundary>

<ErrorBoundary>
      <Footer />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

The error occurs in buyerPage: http://localhost:3000/#/buyer. But the Navbar and Footer components still loads(what I want). When I click Seller from the Navbar, the page link goes to http://localhost:3000/#/seller but the error still shows up unless I manually refresh the page(then it shows the contents of seller page).

Is there a way to automatically refresh the page when we click away from the error page (buyer page in my case)?

Here's my ErrorBoundary code:

```
render() {
        if(this.state.hasError){
            return (
                <div style={errorStyle}>
                     <h2>Something went wrong</h2>
                </div>
            )
        }
        else{
            //refers to the component we are actually rendering
            return (this.props.children);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Inside your `ErrorBoundary` clear the `hasError` on component update:

```
componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
    if (previousProps.children!==this.props.children)
        this.setState({hasError: false});
}
```